# Use Android FileProvider in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to use Android's `FileProvider` in a Delphi mobile app. I have studied many examples, but I could not adapt it to Delphi. I did the arrangements in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. But I could not adapt the schemes in the code block. Please help me convert this code to Delphi.

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", createImageFile());
```

Comment: Any errors or exceptions?

Comment: `.getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider"` You used your package name twice in manifest too?

Comment: Ehhh..... that does not look very much like Delphi code...

Comment: there is no exceptional case. I got this code from the form. I want to adapt it to delphi already in java language. I could not adapt this code to delphi.

Comment: `I could not adapt this code to delphi. ` Well... could not you have told us that right away? And just clearly ask "How to convert this java code to Delphi?".  Your post is a pretty `exceptional case`i believe.

Comment: I am sending a message using an exchange program. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code conversion service, where you post code in one language and your new language of choice and we do the work for you. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to do so yourself and run into problems. When you've done so, post the section of the original code you're having issues converting, your attempt to convert that code, and a clear explanation of the problem you've run into, and ask a specific question related to that problem, and we'll try to help.

Comment: I do not have an inconsistent behavior with site rules and I do not want the code to be prepared. I am aware of the situation here and I want to help you find the fileprovider class in Delphide. But if this desire is irrelevant to the rules of the site, I can handle it on a different tab. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the manifest in order to implement the code you're referring to. One thing that's missing: what does createImageFile() do?

Comment: written as an example. there is a default file path.
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile (context, context.getApplicationContext (). GetPackageName () + ". My.package.name.provider", 'default file');
the problem here is that I can not find the fileprovider class delphide.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may help you.

```
var
 fileuri: JParcelable;
begin
 fileuri := JParcelable (TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile
      (TJFile.JavaClass.init (StringToJString (YOUR_PATH))));
```

Comment: Do you have a example of using file provider to send and intent to open an image with the default android gallery ?